# How to transfer data ViewControllers/classes using NSNotificationCenter?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

I have a table view controller that is supposed to be populated with data from an array that is encapsulated within a `store` class. The table needs to know how many rows are in each section via the method `table:numberOfRowsInSection:`. In this method, I need to return the size of the array that is inside my instance of `store`. I initially did this by making `store` a singleton, but was told this was inefficient and that using NSNotificationCenter would be better.

As far as I know, all NSNotificationCenter does is trigger methods in certain objects when another object posts a specific notification. How can I use NSNotificationCenter to send the size of the array to my table view controller?

Comment: Without information on what the data is it's harder to be sure, but neither `NSNotificationCenter` or a singleton are very good patterns for this. Why not just add a property to your table view controller that points to the `store`? Can you talk more about what the data is?

Comment: It's not a good idea to send the number of rows via notification. Notifications, well, as the name suggests, should be used for notification only. In your case, it should be used to notify that some changes have happened on the store. Real data (e.g. number of rows, sections, etc) are then retrieved from the store instance (either it's a singleton or an instance that the view controller have reference to).

Comment: I have a table view controller that needs to be populated with an array full of strings. This array is a property of another class `Store`. Should I create this store within the initiation of my table view controller and give the table view controller a reference to it?

Comment: update: I've tried the method of giving my table view controller a property that points to store when the table initiates. it seems to be working fine but is this recommended over using a singleton?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
...
// Send 
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: SizeOfRrrayNotification
                                                    object: [NSNumber numberWithInteger: [array count]]];

...
// Subscribe
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                         selector: @selector(sizeOfArray:)
                                             name: SizeOfRrrayNotification
                                           object: nil];

// Get size
- (void) sizeOfArray: (NSNotification*) notification
{
    NSNumber* sizeOfArray = (NSNumber*) notification.object;
    NSLog(@"size of array=%i",  [sizeOfArray integerValue]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Post the Notification :**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MyArraySize" object: [NSNumber numberWithInteger: [myArray count]]] userInfo:nil];
```

**Get the Notification :**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(getSizeOfArray:) name:@"MyArraySize" object:nil];
```

**Add this method in the viewController where you are getting notification:**

```
- (void) getSizeOfArray: (NSNotification*) notification
{
    NSNumber* myArraySize = (NSNumber*) notification.object;
}
```

you can even send more data through "`userInfo`" and get that data in selector method using notification.userInfo, but remember its type is "`NSDictionary`"

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The method in which you are calculating the size of the array:

<------Notification sending side---------->

```
-(void)sizeOfArray{
   int size = [myArray count];
   NSMutableString *myString = [NSMutable string];
   NSString *str = [NSString stringwithFormat:@"%d",size];
   [myString apprndString:str];

//It is to be noted that NSNotification always uses NSobject hence the creation of mystring,instead of just passing size

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"GetSizeOfArray"      object:myString];
}
```

Now once you have posted a notification,add this to the viewDidLoad method of the controller where you are sending the data

<------Notification receiving side---------->

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(get_notified:) name:@"GetSizeOfArray"  object:nil];

//The selector method should always have a notification object as its argument

 [super viewDidLoad];

}


- (void)get_notified:(NSNotification *)notif {
    //This method has notification object in its argument

    if([[notif name] isEqualToString:@"GetSizeOfArray"]){
       NSString *temp = [notif object];
       int size = [temp int value];

       //Data is passed.
        [self.tableView reloadData];  //If its necessary 

     }    
}
```

Hope this helps.